# OSMdroid bounds marker

Tags: osmdroid

////OSMdroid centered on the markers////

I add markers, I need to map the maximum increases or decreases in such a way that all markers were visible

my code:

```
public class mapcode extends Activity {
    globalvar appState;
    int stats=0;
    private MapView mapView;
    private IMapController mapController;
    private SimpleLocationOverlay mMyLocationOverlay;
    private ScaleBarOverlay mScaleBarOverlay;  
    ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> currentLocationOverlay;
    DefaultResourceProxyImpl resourceProxy;
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        
        appState = ((globalvar) getApplicationContext());

        
        
        
        
        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);  
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
      //  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //кнопка ZOOM +-
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        
        mapController = this.mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(2);
        
        this.mMyLocationOverlay = new SimpleLocationOverlay(this);                          
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
        
        this.mScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this);                          
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(mScaleBarOverlay);
//      this.mapView
        
        /////////////////
        resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
        GeoPoint  currentLocation = new GeoPoint(55.860863,37.115046); 
        GeoPoint  currentLocation2 = new GeoPoint(63.557413,-156.102119); 
      
        
        OverlayItem myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", currentLocation);
        Drawable myCurrentLocationMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
        myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(myCurrentLocationMarker);
       // myLocationOverlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER); //no working/
        
        final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);
        
        
        myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", currentLocation2);
        myCurrentLocationMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
        myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(myCurrentLocationMarker);

  //    myLocationOverlayItem.setMarkerHotspot(HotspotPlace.CENTER); // no working

        
        items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);
        
        

        currentLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, resourceProxy);
        
        
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(this.currentLocationOverlay);
}
```

I added two markers, but only one is visible:

[image: image with one marker]

and I need to osmdroid is centered and immediately showed both marker

[image: image with two marker]

Comment: You could use the `zoomToBoundingBox` method, but you would need to go through all of your markers to determine the top, left, bottom, and right coordinates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
for (OverlayItem item : items) {
    GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();
    if (point.getLatitudeE6() < minLat)
        minLat = point.getLatitudeE6();
    if (point.getLatitudeE6() > maxLat)
        maxLat = point.getLatitudeE6();
    if (point.getLongitudeE6() < minLong)
        minLong = point.getLongitudeE6();
    if (point.getLongitudeE6() > maxLong)
        maxLong = point.getLongitudeE6();
}

BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox = new BoundingBoxE6(maxLat, maxLong, minLat, minLong);
mMapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox);
```

Comment: adding `mapController = mMapView.getController(); mapController.zoomToSpan(boundingBox.getLatitudeSpanE6(), boundingBox.getLongitudeSpanE6()); mapController.setCenter(boundingBox.getCenter());`

 after `mMapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox);` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Unable to see all markers even i set the 
 BoundingBox boundingBox = new BoundingBox(north, west, south, east);
boundingBox.getLongitudeSpanWithDateLine();
mMapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, true);

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate boundingBox by `BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints(geoPoints)`

```
fun zoomToBounds(points: List<LatLng>) {
    val geoPoints = points.map { GeoPoint(it.latitude, it.longitude) }
    val boundingBox = BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints(geoPoints)
    mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, true)
}
```

It is also possible to have some paddings by using `zoomtoBoundingBox` overloaded method and setting the `pBorderSizeInPixels` parameter

```
public double zoomToBoundingBox(
    final BoundingBox pBoundingBox, 
    final boolean pAnimated, 
    final int pBorderSizeInPixels, 
    final double pMaximumZoom, 
    final Long pAnimationSpeed
)
```