# OSMDroid Set Zoom for Show All Marker (bounding Marker)

Tags: android, zooming, marker, osmdroid

I use OSMDroid for mapview library.

[OSMdroid bounds marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842526/osmdroid-bounds-marker)
form this link i understand for use `zoomToBoundingBox` method

when I have 20 marker on map 
I want to visible on display. 
how to use zoomToBoundingBox,

or how to set (north, east, south, west) of BoundingBoxE6
or (northE6, eastE6, southE6, westE6)

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OSMdroid bounds marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842526/osmdroid-bounds-marker)

Comment: Thank,but i try to do with 1 marker then zoom to min_zoom_Level. why dont zoom to max_zoom_level for show 1 marker.Or sometime marker is nearest other marker it zom fit to zoom map. Thank you